# Generate callview tree of a C project

Tags: c, ctags

I have to work with a fairly obscure C project which is about 500 files and 250k lines with almost no documentation. Worse, half of the project is written in assembly. I know, this is ridiculous...

Anyway, to get a general overview of the code structure, I would like to generate a call-tree view a bit better than what Doxygen can do with [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

So I am about to write my own parser and viewer using [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)'s output and [cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/). But before that, would like to know if such good programs are already available and usable with imperative languages.

For example this is what I am expecting for the code below

main.c

```
void main() {
   foo(1);
}
```

foo.c

```
void foo(int a) {
   bar(a);
   baz(a);
}

void baz(int a) {
   bar(2);
}
```

Output:

```
+------+     +----------+      +----------+        +----------+
|main.c|     |foo.c     |      |foo.c     |        |bar.c     |
|main()|---->|foo(int a)|--+-->|foo(int a)|------->|bar(int a)|
+------+     +----------+  |   +----------+        +----------+
                           |                             ^     
                           |   +----------+              |     
                           |   |foo.c     |              |     
                           +-->|baz(int a)|--------------+     
                               +----------+
```

Comment: There's a POSIX command [`cflow`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cflow.html)
and there's a GNU implemention of [`cflow`](http://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/).  That should identify the calling graph.  Presenting that coherently might be more of a problem.  There must be tools to do it already available.  In your diagram, why is `foo()` documented as if it is recursive (calls `foo()`)?

Comment: what OS do you have? it is relevant to the question.

Comment: @CyberSpock I would say Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a look at CodeQuery: https://ruben2020.github.io/codequery/

It pulls in ctags and cscope databases and does all sorts of fancy stuff, including (apparently) generating call graphs, though I've never tried that particular feature. It also supports a lot more than C.